# How can I force double quotes into my string value

Tags: c#

I need to pass a string value that looks like this:

```
"<CREDS email="billybong@domain.com" myvalue="hampset" />"
```

the call is to set it is :

```
var valToPass = "<CREDS email="\"" + email + "\"" myvalue="\"" + password +  "\"" />";
```

but valToPass ends up looking like:

```
"<CREDS email=\"billybong@domain.com\" myvalue=\"hampset\" />"
```

It then passed this as a string literal. I don't want the slashes going with the string as I'm passing the value to a blackbox routine written in Delphi.

How can I format my string correctly?

Comment: Does that code actually compile?

Comment: “ends up looking like” **where**? In the debugger? The debugger shows encoded strings (" displays as \", newlines as \n) so you can see whitespace. What does the visualizer (the magnifying glass icon) display?

Comment: Double check how you're escaping your `"` .

Comment: Are you trying to construct HTML using string concatenation? Save yourself hours of frustration by using [`HtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.htmlstring?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: xml/html can use a single quote to specify attributes: `"<CREDS email='billybong@domain.com' myvalue='hampset' />"`

Comment: Those slashes won't end up in the string. They're only there so the compiler knows you're not closing the string with that character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using string.Format and escaping double quotes with '\'. It makes it a little bit more readable, especially when you need to do more changes to the template string:

```
var escapedEmail = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(email);
var escapedPassword = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(password);
var valToPass = string.Format("<CREDS email=\"{0}\" myvalue=\"{1}\" />", escapedEmail , escapedPassword );
```

It is also important to escape you input values, otherwise your output string becomes vulnerable to XML injections.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is html or xml: `"<CREDS email="billybong@domain.com" myvalue="hampset" />"`

Therefore, I dare to suggest a method using XElement.

```
string email = "billybong@domain.com";
string password = "hampset";

XElement xml = new XElement("CREDS",
    new XAttribute("email", email),
    new XAttribute("myValue", password));

string result = xml.ToString();
```

This simple method is guaranteed to produce a valid result with escaped values.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
var valToPass = "<CREDS email=\"" + email + "\" myvalue=\"" + password +  "\" />";
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to [HTML injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368473/prevent-html-injection). What if my password was `"/><script>window.location.replace("spamURL")</script>`

Comment: The answer could be improved by explaining why string concatenation in OP's context is a security risk and should never be attempted, and present a secure version of the suggested fix.